# Retrieving Hidden input value using java

Tags: java, html

I have a requirment. I have placed a Hidden field  in my HTML. I want to retrieve that hidden text value from Java. Is there any way to do it? I know we can do it in javascript but i need to extract the value from java.
I have created a hidden text field like this:

```
<input type="HIDDEN" name="X" value="2356544">
```

I want to retrieve 2356544 through java.
Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: How is Java getting this? Is it a URL, html file, a String, or a form submission?

Comment: What I am doing is, I have a bounced email which is in HTML format. In the email, I have put this hidden field in order to track the email which I will be sending after some time. I want to extract the Hidden field and store it in some variable for future use. Please let me know how i can achieve this. Let me know if i can achieve this without using JSP or servlets. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Servlets you can retrive the value of a parameter with

```
request.getParameter("X");
```

or if you have a JSP then use

```
Hello <c:out value="${param.X}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a web application since it is using html. So in a web application you have request object, so you can use

request.getParameter("X") from your servlet or action.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

create id attribute in hidden field as id="X"  then in javascript take value using id

```
var value=document.getElementById('X').value;
```

**or**

using name

```
 var value=document.getElementsByName('X').value;
```